# How to configure offsets paramter while constructing ProducerMessage in Akka Streams Kafka?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, akka-stream, reactive-kafka

I am using Scala 2.11 and Akka Streams Kafka 0.17.

I have a **stream** where:

- A `Source` is created using [`Source.actorRef`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/stream/stream-integrations.html#source-actorref). Here, the actor is scheduled to run at some regular interval and generate messages continuously, which are emitted to the stream.
- I have attached a `Producer` as a `Flow`. The producer pushes `ProducerMessage.Message` to a Kafka topic.
- Some DB operations.

I have a problem while constructing the `ProducerMessage.Message`, which looks like:

```
final case class Message[K, V, +PassThrough](
    record: ProducerRecord[K, V],
    passThrough: PassThrough
  )
```

I can easily pass the `record` parameter which contains the actual message. But I don't know what to pass in the `passThrough` parameter. According to the [docs](https://github.com/akka/reactive-kafka/blob/v0.17/core/src/main/scala/akka/kafka/ProducerMessage.scala#L21):

> The `passThrough` field may hold any element that is passed through
>   the `Consumer#flow` and included in the `Result`. That is useful
>   when some context is needed to be passed on downstream operations.
>   That could be done with unzip/zip, but this is more convenient. It can
>   for example be a `ConsumerMessage.CommittableOffset` or
>   `ConsumerMessage.CommittableOffsetBatch` that can be committed later
>   in the flow.

In my case there is no any Kafka consumer subscribing to a Kafka topic and generating a `Source` (`comittableSource` or `plainSource`) for my stream. In that case, I would have passed the consumer offset as described in the docs. But in my case, an actor is simulating such a consumer. That means I don't have access to `ConsumerMessage.CommittableOffset`. So what do I pass in for the `passThrough` parameter here? What would be the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 0):

After forwarding my issue with the `reactive-kafka` team, I got my answer. Basically,what they said was, if you do not have a use case to `pass through` anything,you can try setting it to **None** or **NotUsed**, or perhaps just the empty String **""**.

Also note that if you use perhaps a `Producer.plainSink` you do not need to construct a `ProducerMessage.Message`. Then, you can directly construct a Kafka `ProducerRecord`.
That `ProducerMessage.Message` case class is just a container for the cases where `pass through` is desired or needed. Other than the element to be passed through, it just contains a Kafka `ProducerRecord`.